# How to correctly CloudDeploy code which contains non-English characters?

Tags: character-encoding, deployment, cloud-deploy

As an illustration：

```
CloudDeploy[{"中文"}]
```

will give a url. After open it, I got following on the web page

```
{\:4e2d\:6587}
```

instead of `{中文}` which is not right.

My question is : How to correctly CloudDeploy code which contains non-English characters?

---

**update**

As  Sascha pointed out, in the latest Mathematica 11, we got more problem. `CloudDeploy[{"中文"}]` directly gives an error message before it connect to Wolfram Cloud.

> BinaryWrite::nocoerce: {中文} cannot be coerced to the specified format.

What is wrong?

---

**update : minimal real working example**

```
Clear[fillInHeader];
fillInHeader[data_, head_] := 
  Join[Transpose[{Join[{""}, head[[1]]]}], Join[head[[{2}]], data], 2];

Clear[vacancyCheck];
vacancyCheck[classList_, period_, day_] :=
  If[Head[classList] === List,
   Select[
     Thread[classList -> (classList /. finalDataRule)], #[[2, 
        period + 1, day + 2]] === {} &][[;; , 1]],
   Select[{classList -> (classList /. finalDataRule)}, #[[2, 
        period + 1, day + 2]] === {} &][[;; , 1]]];

Clear[vacancyTable];
vacancyTable[classList_] := 
  Module[{data = 
     Table[vacancyCheck[classList, period, day], {period, 1, 5}, {day,
        1, 5}]},
   data[[3, 3]] = Null;
   data[[4, 3]] = Null; 
   Grid[fillInHeader[
     data, {{"1-2", "3-5", "6-7", "8-9", "10-12"}, {"星期一", "星期二", 
       "星期三", "星期四", "星期五"}}], Frame -> All]];

allClassList = {"水文15-1", "水工15-1"};
finalDataRule = {"水文15-1" -> {{{"时间", "早晨"}, {}, {"星期一", ""}, {"星期二", 
       ""}, {"星期三", ""}, {"星期四", ""}, {"星期五", ""}, {"星期六", 
       ""}, {"星期日", ""}}, {{"中", "", "", ""}, {"中", "", "", 
       "中"}, {"中（中）", "1-14(1,2)", "中", "中C104"}, {}, {"中", 
       "1-3,5-15(1,2)", "中", "中A107"}, {}, {}, {}, {}}, {{}, {"中", "",
        "", "中", "中"}, {"中", "1-16(3,4,5)", "中", "中C107", ""}, {"中", 
       "1-3,5-15(3,4)", "中", "中A107", ""}, {"中（中）", "1-14(3,4)", "中", 
       "中C104", ""}, {"中", "1-16(3,4)", "中", "中C306", ""}, {"中", 
       "1-16(3,4,5)", "中", "中C103", ""}, {}, {}}, {{"中", "", "", 
       ""}, {"中", "", "", "中"}, {}, {"中(中)", "2中/中", "", 
       ""}, {}, {"中A(中)", "1-16(6,7)", "中", "中302"}, {"中(2)", 
       "1-16(6,7)", "中", "中C103"}, {}, {}}, {{}, {"中", "", "", "", 
       "中"}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {"中(2)", "1-16(8)", "中", "中C103", 
       ""}, {}, {}}, {{"中", "", ""}, {"中10中", "中11中", 
       "中12中"}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}}, 
   "水工15-1" -> {{{"时间", "早晨"}, {}, {"星期一", ""}, {"星期二", ""}, {"星期三", 
       ""}, {"星期四", ""}, {"星期五", ""}, {"星期六", ""}, {"星期日", 
       ""}}, {{"中", "", "", ""}, {"中", "", "", "中"}, {"中（中）", 
       "1-14(1,2)", "中", "中B201"}, {"中", "1-3,5-17(1,2)", "中", 
       "中C506"}, {}, {}, {"中", "1-3,5-17(1,2)", "中", 
       "中C506"}, {}, {}}, {{}, {"中", "", "", "中", "中"}, {"中", 
       "1-3,5-17(3,4,5)", "中", "中C405", ""}, {"中", "1-16(3,4,5)", "中",
        "中C105", ""}, {"中（中）", "1-14(3,4)", "中", "中B201", 
       ""}, {"中(2)", "1-16(3,4,5)", "中", "中C103", ""}, {"中", 
       "1-16(3,4,5)", "中", "中C201", ""}, {}, {}}, {{"中", "", "", 
       ""}, {"中", "", "", "中"}, {}, {"中(中)", "2中/中", "", 
       ""}, {}, {"中", "1-3,5-17(6,7)", "中", 
       "中B201"}, {}, {}, {}}, {{}, {"中", "", "", 
       "中"}, {}, {}, {}, {"中A(中)", "1-16(8,9)", "中1", 
       "中C203"}, {}, {}, {}}, {{"中", "", ""}, {"中10中", "中11中", 
       "中12中"}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}}};
obj = CloudDeploy[
  DynamicModule[{classList}, 
   Manipulate[(vacancyTable[classList]), 
    ButtonBar[{"重置" :> (classList = {})}], {{classList, {}, "班级"}, 
     allClassList, Appearance -> "Row"}, ControlType -> TogglerBar, 
    SaveDefinitions -> True]], Permissions -> {All -> All}]
```

Notice I used `Permissions -> {All -> All}`, because I want everyone could access this. If I sign in wolfram Cloud in the browser. I got

[image]

The only problem is character encoding.

However, if I open the url without sign in wolfram cloud in the browser, I got "Interactivity is not enabled." error

[image]

Comment: Relevant: `\:XXXX` is a _Mathematica_ notation of [inserting characters using the character code](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CharacterCodes.html).

Comment: @JHM Thanks JHM. But this is not the solution. How to Deploy directly with correct encoding? Some options?

Comment: In Version 11.0.0.0 `CloudDeploy` will fail with an `BinaryWrite::nocoerce: 中文 cannot be coerced to the specified format.`-message

Comment: @Sascha What does it mean? I am using 10.4, shows no error message.

Comment: Hi, @Sascha. I can confirm your observations now. I am surprised that after so many days, there is still no solution.

Comment: @matheorem what is the goal? I can't make it work with HTML as a target but this works so so: `CloudDeploy[ ExportForm["\"中文\"", "CloudCDF"] ]`

Comment: @Kuba Happy to see you, Kuba : ) Finally, someone is interested in my post. My post is just an illustration. What I really want to do is deploy a `Manipulate`. Since the data I have to process contains a lot of Chinese characters, so those function I wrote in the intermediate steps to process the data also contains Chinese characters. So simple `ExportForm` probably won't solve the problem

Comment: @Kuba To get a feeling, this is something I finally want to deploy http://pasteboard.co/cr2CMmVZz.png

Comment: @Kuba I import a microsoft excel file which contains Chinese into mathematica and I then process it.

Comment: @Kuba Thank you so much, Kuba. I packed everything cleanly in a notebook file. Can be downloaded here http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=03775586248323193603

Comment: @Kuba During preparing this nb file. I found another problem. Because I want this manipulate can be accessed by other people, so I set `Permission->{All->All}`, However, I got `Interactivity is not enabled.` when I open url without sign in.

Comment: @Kuba No, that is just a typo. In mathematica, I make it right for there is autocompletion : )

Comment: @Kuba Hi, kuba. Sorry for that. I previously thought no one interested in it except you, so I just leave the post unchanged. I have updated my post now.

Comment: @matheorem it doesn't work withput a minimal example of `allClassList` and `vacancyList`, it can't be skipped but the point is the code is not working standalone.

Comment: @Kuba I don't understand. Do you mean the notebook file you download can't run properly? But I just tested it, the manipulate is all right.

Comment: @matheorem the code in the question is not self contained. I'm not planning to download a notebook and many others won't either. They are not secure. Nothing personal, I just don't do that.

Comment: @Kuba Hi, kuba. I tried to reduce the problem to minimal code example so that you can directly copy it. However, you know there is bug of stack exchange, if I wrote too many Chinese characters, the system thought I am spanning. I just can't update my post, sorry for that.

Comment: @matheorem so reduce number of them?

Comment: @Kuba What is "reduce number of them"?

Comment: "if I wrote too many Chinese characters," - can't you prepare self contained example with e.g. two characters?